# How to reduce the gap between link images in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have started to create a Sharepoint site in Sharepoint ins office 365 and have selected a communication site as it is going to be about our company's services.

I want to add a few external links at the bottom of the site so I have used the "Quick Links" option but it leaves a large space between each icon using the "compact" option (see image below) and when I try the other options like "filmstrip" it makes the icons too big.

How can I change it so the icons are closer together?  I have looked at columns but it only allows 3 and I have more icons than that.

Thanks for any help

**Big gap between icons:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Deploy [SPFx react-script-editor](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) to your tenant and add to communication site so you could override default CSS.

Sample demo:

[image]

[image]

```
<style>
div[role="listitem"]{
width:160px !important;
}
</style>
```

[image]